# How do I calculate a distinct running country count for my query?

Tags: sql

I have a table with a user "id", the "country" they are from, and the "year" they signed up, for example:

| id | country | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 2010 |
| 2 | Mexico | 2010 |
| 3 | USA | 2011 |
| 4 | India | 2011 |
| 5 | Japan | 2011 |

I am trying to calculate the running count of distinct countries by year. So the final output for the example above should be:

| year | country_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 2 |
| 2011 | 4 |

I wrote something along these lines but obviously this is flawed logic since the 2nd half of the query isn't a distinct count:

```
with t1 as (
select year, count(distinct country) country_count
from data
group by 1 order by 1
)

select *, sum(country_count) over (order by year) AS cumulative_country_count
from t1
```

Comment: So what have you got so far by way of an attempt

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question please

Comment: It is often handy if your example data and the required results actually match up amd make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  distinct year
       ,count(country) over(order by year) as cnt
from    (
        select   * 
                  ,row_number() over(partition by country order by year) as rn
         from     t
        ) t
where   rn = 1
```

| year | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 2 |
| 2011 | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6vCMEwxj?hide=8)

Comment: I did it so it would eliminate the later duplicates and not the first one.